# Dovecot: Username character disallowed by auth_username_chars: 0x0a

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server, dovecot, sasl

I'm trying to set up a postfix+dovecot server to use GNU Mailman for creating a mailing list server, however I'm currently stuck at setting up SASL authentication using dovecot. It seems to add a newline character to the base64 encoded username

**Note -** I've hidden my actual domain name and replaced it with `mail.example.org` and my public IP with `X.X.X.X`

The telnet session looks like this

```
sh-5.0$ telnet mail.example.org 25
Trying X.X.X.X...
Connected to mail.example.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.example.org ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
EHLO mail.example.org
250-mail.example.org
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250 SMTPUTF8
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
Y29jb2EK
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: VXNlcm5hbWU6
```

The username is `cocoa`, and I encoded it using `echo cocoa | openssl base64`. Now when I check my dovecot logs:

```
Jan 07 11:28:51 master: Info: Dovecot v2.2.33.2 (d6601f4ec) starting up without any protocols (core dumps disabled)
Jan 07 11:29:06 auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth
Jan 07 11:29:06 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/auth/lib20_auth_var_expand_crypt.so
Jan 07 11:29:06 auth: Debug: Wrote new auth token secret to /var/run/dovecot/auth-token-secret.dat
Jan 07 11:29:06 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=0)
Jan 07 11:29:52 auth: Debug: client in: AUTH    1   PLAIN   service=smtp    nologin lip=X.X.X.X rip=106.202.14.226  resp=<hidden>
Jan 07 11:29:52 auth: Info: pam(cocoa,106.202.14.226): Attempted login with password having illegal chars
Jan 07 11:29:54 auth: Debug: client passdb out: FAIL    1   user=cocoa
Jan 07 11:30:48 auth: Debug: client in: AUTH    2   LOGIN   service=smtp    nologin lip=X.X.X.X rip=106.202.14.226
Jan 07 11:30:48 auth: Debug: client passdb out: CONT    2   VXNlcm5hbWU6
Jan 07 11:30:51 auth: Debug: client in: CONT<hidden>
Jan 07 11:30:51 auth: Info: login(?,106.202.14.226): Username character disallowed by auth_username_chars: 0x0a (username: cocoa?)
Jan 07 11:30:53 auth: Debug: client passdb out: FAIL    2   user=cocoan original_user=cocoan
Jan 07 11:31:44 auth: Debug: client in: AUTH    3   LOGIN   service=smtp    nologin lip=X.X.X.X rip=106.202.14.226
Jan 07 11:31:44 auth: Debug: client passdb out: CONT    3   VXNlcm5hbWU6
Jan 07 11:31:57 auth: Debug: client in: CONT<hidden>
Jan 07 11:31:57 auth: Info: login(?,106.202.14.226): Username character disallowed by auth_username_chars: 0x0a (username: cocoa?)
Jan 07 11:31:59 auth: Debug: client passdb out: FAIL    3   user=cocoan original_user=cocoan
```

The logs seems to say that the username is `cocoan` whereas I encoded `cocoa`. I suspect the `n` is from the `\n` character somehow? But I'm not sure how it's being added

My dovecot.conf looks like this

```
root@mail:/etc/dovecot# cat dovecot.conf | grep -v ^#

!include_try /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/*.protocol
dict {
  #quota = mysql:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext
  #expire = sqlite:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext
}
!include conf.d/*.conf
!include_try local.conf
```

The only files I've edited are `10-auth.conf`

```
auth_mechanisms = plain login
!include auth-system.conf.ext
```

And `10-master.conf`'s `service auth {}` block

```
service auth {

  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    #mode = 0666
    #user = 
    #group = 
  }

  # Postfix smtp-auth
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }

  # Auth process is run as this user.
  #user = $default_internal_user
}
```

Lastly, my `postfix.conf` looks like this

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.example.org
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, mail.example.org, localhost.example.org, , localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

I would really appreciate any help. I've been stuck on this for the past two days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I posted the same question on reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/elhfbn/dovecot_username_character_disallowed_by_auth/) and reddit user [slugonamission](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/elhfbn/dovecot_username_character_disallowed_by_auth/fdhw8go?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) correctly pointed out that `echo` adds a newline character by default, so I had to do `echo -n cocoa | openssl base64` rather than `echo cocoa | openssl base64`

I'll leave this up in case anybody is as oblivious as I am

Comment: Have to login and give you an upvote. Exact same issue and I have no idea why 'echo' is this tricky